# Setting values to columns of a multi-hierarchical pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-hierarchical pandas dataframe shown below.  How, for a given attribute, attr ('rh', 'T', 'V'), can I set certain values (say values > 0.5) to NaN over the ***entire set*** of pLevs?  I have seen answers on how to set a specific column (e.g., df['rh', 50]) but have not seen how to select the entire set.

> ```
> attr      rh                             T                             V  
> pLev       50        75        100       50        75        100       50        75        100            
> refIdx    
> 0       0.225026  0.013868  0.306472  0.144581  0.379578  0.760685  0.686463  0.476179  0.185635   
> 1       0.496020  0.956295  0.471268  0.492284  0.836456  0.852873  0.088977  0.090494  0.604290   
> 2       0.898723  0.733030  0.175646  0.841776  0.517127  0.685937  0.094648  0.857104  0.135651    
> 3       0.136525  0.443102  0.759630  0.148536  0.426558  0.731955  0.523390  0.965385  0.094153
> ```

To facilitate assistance, I am including code to create the dataframe here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,9)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['rh','T','V'],[50,75,100]])
df.columns.names = ['attr', 'pLev']
df.index.name = 'refIdx'
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation is mildly annoying but you can use [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)

```
df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['rh',:]]=np.nan
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I get this error: 
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'

Also, assuming this would work, what syntax would I use to set a limited set of values, say values>0.5, to nan?

Comment: Yes, you will need to sort the index (use `.sort_index()`) for this (it works on your example as is). Since you only care about the first level of the index, you can also shortcut it as `df.loc[:,'rh']`

Comment: `.applymap(lambda x:x if x<=0.5 else np.nan)` would be one way (probably not the fastest but maybe the simplest)

Comment: So far, so good....yet there is one more step that I have yet to be successful with.  I want to modify the original data frame. (I apologize that I wasn't clear about that.)  I've tried the pandas update function but no luck:
`df.update(df.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['rh',:]].applymap(lambda x : x if x<=0.5 else np.nan))`

Comment: The result with the code above just returns my original data with no error even though the the chain of code within the parenthesis returns what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'given attribute' is `'rh'` then you can take a cross-section with the following:

```
df_xs = df.xs('rh', level='attr', axis=1, drop_level=False)
```

Then you can update the original `df` as follows:

```
df[df_xs > 0.5] = np.nan
```

This works because `drop_level=False` was given to `.xs`